# merge TSV files together in command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, awk, paste

I have 2 TSV files:
file 1 has columns A, B, C
file 2 has columns D

I want to merge them to get file 3 (TSV) which has columns A,B,C,D

I tried doing `paste -d, file1 file2 > file3` but after they merge, columns C,D are combined into one column separated by a comma.

Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are explicitly instructing paste to join with a comma: remove `-d,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forcing the delimiter to be comma.  Just remove `-d,`, by default the delimiter is tab.

Answer (score -3):

From my situation, the paste command didn't work on linux system [ubuntu16.04], not know why. but using this command is ok [pure python code]:

```
open('newfile.tsv', 'w').write(open('f1.tsv').read() + open('f2.tsv').read())
```

Comment: This command is not working according to the question. What it does is, first it puts the data at A B C then the data in D below them.